# Check if col value is like a dict value of list type

Tags: regex, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to take my dictionary "terms_by_country" which contains suffixes of a company (e.g. LLC) and check a column in a PySpark df to see if that suffix exists and if so then return the country name from the dictionary in a new column.

The problem looks like this:

```py
terms_by_country = {
   'Albania': ['sh.a.', 'sh.p.k.'],
   'Argentina': ['s.a.', 's.r.l.', 's.c.p.a', 'scpa', 's.c.e i.', 's.e.', 's.g.r',
      'soc.col.'
   ],
   'Australia': ['nl', 'pty. ltd.', 'pty ltd'],
   'Austria': ['e.u.', 'stg', 'gesbr', 'a.g.', 'ag', 'og', 'kg'],
   'Belarus': ['aat', '3at'],
   'Belgium': ['esv', 'vzw', 'vof', 'snc', 'comm.v', 'scs', 'bvba', 'sprl', 'cvba',
      'cvoa', 'sca', 'sep', 'gie'
   ],
   'Bosnia / Herzegovina': ['d.d.', 'a.d.', 'd.n.o.', 'd.o.o.', 'k.v.', 's.p.'],
   'Brazil': ['ltda', 's.a.', 'pllc', 'ad', 'adsitz', 'ead', 'et', 'kd', 'kda', 'sd'],
   'Bulgaria': ['ad', 'adsitz', 'ead', 'et', 'kd', 'kda', 'sd'],
   'Cambodia': ['gp', 'sm pte ltd.', 'pte ltd.', 'plc ltd.', 'peec', 'sp'],
   'Canada': ['gp', 'lp', 'sp'],
   'Chile': ['eirl', 's.a.', 'sgr', 's.g.r.', 'ltda', 's.p.a.', 'sa', 's. en c.',
      'ltda.'
   ],
   'Columbia': ['s.a.', 'e.u.', 's.a.s.', 'suc. de descendants', 'sca'],
   'Croatia': ['d.d.', 'd.o.o.', 'obrt'],
   'Czech Republic': ['a.s.', 'akc. spol.', 's.r.o.', 'spol. s r.o.', 'v.o.s.', u've\xc5\x99. obch. spol.', 'a spol.', 'k.s.', 'kom. spol.', 'kom. spol.'],
   'Denmark': ['i/s', 'a/s', 'k/s', 'p/s', 'amba', 'a.m.b.a.', 'fmba', 'f.m.b.a.', 'smba',
      's.m.b.a.', 'g/s'
   ],
   'Dominican Republic': ['c. por a.', 'cxa', 's.a.', 's.a.s.', 'srl.', 'srl', 'eirl.', 'sa',
      'sas'
   ],
   'Ecuador': ['s.a.', 'c.a.', 'sa', 'ep'],
   'Egypt': ['sae'],
   'Estonia': ['fie'],
   'Finland': ['t:mi', 'tmi', 'as oy', 'as.oy', 'ay', 'ky', 'oy', 'oyj', 'ok'],
   'France': ['sicav', 'sarl', 'sogepa', 'ei', 'eurl', 'sasu', 'fcp', 'gie', 'sep', 'snc',
      'scs', 'sca', 'scop', 'sem', 'sas'
   ],
   'Germany': ['gmbh & co. kg', 'e.g.', 'e.v.', 'gbr', 'ohg', 'partg',
      'kgaa', 'gmbh', 'g.m.b.h.', 'ag', 'mbh & co. kg'
   ],
   'Greece': ['a.e.', 'ae', 'e.e.', 'ee', 'epe', 'e.p.e.', 'mepe', 'm.e.p.e.', 'o.e.',
      'oe', 'ovee', 'o.v.e.e.'
   ],
   'Guatemala': ['s.a.', 'sa'],
   'Haiti': ['sa'],
   'Hong Kong': ['ltd', 'unltd', 'ultd', 'limited'],
   'Hungary': ['e.v.', 'e.c.', 'bt.', 'kft.', 'kht.', 'kkt.', 'k.v.', 'zrt.', 'nyrt',
      'ev', 'ec', 'rt.'
   ],
   'Iceland': ['ehf.', 'hf.', 'ohf.', 's.f.', 'ses.'],
   'India': ['pvt. ltd.', 'ltd.', 'psu', 'pse'],
   'Indonesia': ['ud', 'fa', 'pt'],
   'Ireland': ['cpt', 'teo'],
   'Israel': ['b.m.', 'bm', 'ltd', 'limited'],
   'Italy': ['s.n.c.', 's.a.s.', 's.p.a.', 's.a.p.a.', 's.r.l.', 's.c.r.l.', 's.s.'],
   'Latvia': ['as', 'sia', 'ik', 'ps', 'ks'],
   'Lebanon': ['sal'],
   'Lithuania': ['uab', 'ab', 'ij', 'mb'],
   'Luxemborg': ['s.a.', 's.a.r.l.', 'secs'],
   'Macedonia': ['d.o.o.', 'd.o.o.e.l', 'k.d.a.', 'j.t.d.', 'a.d.', 'k.d.'],
   'Malaysia': ['bhd.', 'sdn. bhd.'],
   'Mexico': ['s.a.', 's. de. r.l.', 's. en c.', 's.a.b.', 's.a.p.i.'],
   'Mongolia': ['xk', 'xxk'],
   'Netherlands': ['v.o.f.', 'c.v.', 'b.v.', 'n.v.'],
   'New Zealand': ['tapui', 'ltd', 'limited'],
   'Nigeria': ['gte.', 'plc', 'ltd.', 'ultd.'],
   'Norway': ['asa', 'as', 'ans', 'ba', 'bl', 'da', 'etat', 'fkf', 'hf', 'iks', 'kf',
      'ks', 'nuf', 'rhf', 'sf'
   ],
   'Oman': ['saog', 'saoc'],
   'Pakistan': ['ltd.', 'pvt. ltd.', 'ltd', 'limited'],
   'Peru': ['sa', 's.a.', 's.a.a.'],
   'Philippines': ['coop.', 'corp.', 'corp', 'ent.', 'inc.', 'inc', 'llc', 'l.l.c.',
      'ltd.'
   ],
   'Poland': ['p.p.', 's.k.a.', 'sp.j.', 'sp.k.', 'sp.p.', 'sp. z.o.o.', 's.c.', 's.a.'],
   'Portugal': ['lda.', 'crl', 's.a.', 's.f.', 'sgps'],
   'Romania': ['s.c.a.', 's.c.s.', 's.n.c.', 's.r.l.', 'o.n.g.', 's.a.'],
   'Russia': ['ooo', 'oao', 'zao', '3ao', 'пао', 'оао', 'ооо'],
   'Serbia': ['d.o.o.', 'a.d.', 'k.d.', 'o.d.'],
   'Singapore': ['bhd', 'pte ltd', 'sdn bhd', 'llp', 'l.l.p.', 'ltd.', 'pte', 'pte. ltd.'],
   'Slovenia': ['d.d.', 'd.o.o.', 'd.n.o.', 'k.d.', 's.p.'],
   'Slovakia': ['a.s.', 'akc. spol.', 's.r.o.', 'spol. s r.o.', 'k.s.', 'kom. spol.', 'v.o.s.', 'a spol.'],
   'Spain': ['s.a.', 's.a.d.', 's.l.', 's.l.l.', 's.l.n.e.', 's.c.', 's.cra', 's.coop',
      'sal', 'sccl'
   ],
   'Sweden': ['ab', 'hb', 'kb'],
   'Switzerland': ['ab', 'sa', 'gmbh', 'g.m.b.h.', 'sarl', 'sagl'],
   'Turkey': ['koop.'],
   'Ukraine': ['dat', 'fop', 'kt', 'pt', 'tdv', 'tov', 'pp', 'vat', 'zat', 'at'],
   'United Kingdom': ['plc.', 'plc', 'cic', 'cio', 'l.l.p.', 'llp', 'l.p.', 'lp', 'ltd.',
      'ltd', 'limited'],
   'United States of America': ['llc', 'inc.', 'corporation', 'incorporated', 'company',
      'limited', 'corp.', 'inc.', 'inc', 'llp', 'l.l.p.', 'pllc', 'and company',
      '& company', 'inc', 'inc.', 'corp.', 'corp', 'ltd.', 'ltd', '& co.', '& co', 'co.',
      'co', 'lp', 'USA', 'american', '(US)', '(USA)'],
   'Uzbekistan': ['mchj', 'qmj', 'aj', 'oaj', 'yoaj', 'xk', 'xt', 'ok', 'uk', 'qk']
}
```

I've created a PySpark dataframe from it:

```py
keywords = spark.createDataFrame([[k,v] for (k,v) in terms_by_country.items()]).toDF('country', 'value')
```

And I'm trying to check if country name is present in organization

```
+-----+--------------------------------------+
| id  |org_name                              |
+-----+--------------------------------------+
|1    |Pro Vera SA                           |
|2    |Aurohealth LLC                        |
|3    |Novartis Pharmaceuticals Corporation  |
|4    |American Sales Company                |
|     |Zydus Pharmaceuticals (USA) Inc.      |
+-----+--------------------------------------+
```

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

fda_manuf = fda_manuf.join(
    keywords, 
    F.expr("lower(manuf_name) rlike '\\\\b' || lower(country) || '\\\\b'"),
    'left'
)

fda_manuf.display()
```

But I don't want it to just go through the names, I want it to go through the lists and compare the organization acronyms with the list above and get the country name, but couldn't figure out how to compare string with a column containing lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) the array type column before the join.

```py
fda_manuf = fda_manuf.join(
    keywords.withColumn('value', F.explode('value')), 
    F.expr("lower(manuf_name) rlike '\\\\b' || lower(value) || '\\\\b'"),
    'left'
)
```